# VBScript string replace with range instead of string?

Tags: string, vbscript, replace

[Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) already exists, but that function takes strings as parameters. I need range.

In my string there are two "strings" that are 10 characters long. 
Greger with 6 chars and 4 spaces and the other string with 10 characters.

```
"Greger    AASSDDFFGG"
```

I want to replace `"Greger    "` with `"googlioa  "`

What i'm looking for is basically this:

```
Replace(MyString,1,10) = "googlioa  "
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace strictly by position, use concatenation of Left(),  new, and Mid(). To get you started:

```
>> Function replByPos(s, f, l, n)
>>   replByPos = Left(s, f-1) & n & Mid(s, f + l - 1)
>> End Function
>> s = "Greger    AASSDDFFGG"
>> r = replByPos(s, 1, 10, "googlioa ")
>> WScript.Echo s
>> WScript.Echo r
>>
Greger    AASSDDFFGG
googlioa  AASSDDFFGG
>>
```

Further enhancements:

1. safety: `f(rom) - 1` is risky - should be checked
2. padding of new string wrt l(ength)
3. perhaps you want to search (Instr()) for old ("Greger ") before the concatenation

**On second thought (and stealing Bond's padding):**

Maybe I should have interpeted the 10 as a to/till/upto value instead of a length/width specification. So see whether

```
Option Explicit

Function replByPos(src, from, till, ns)
  Dim w : w = till - from
  replByPos = Left(src, from - 1) & Left(ns & Space(w), w) & Mid(src, till)
End Function

Dim s  : s  = "Greger    AASSDDFFGG"
Dim ns : ns = "googlioa"

WScript.Echo s
WScript.Echo replByPos(s, 1, 10, ns)

s  = "Whatever Greger    AASSDDFFGG"
ns = "googlioa"

Dim p : p = Instr(s, "Greger")
WScript.Echo s
WScript.Echo replByPos(s, p, p + 10, ns)
```

output:

```
cscript 22811896.vbs
Greger    AASSDDFFGG
googlioa  AASSDDFFGG
Whatever Greger    AASSDDFFGG
Whatever googlioa  AASSDDFFGG
```

matches your specs better.

Comment: This pretty much does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If they're always going to be 10 chars, just pad the names.

```
strNameFind    = "Greger"
strNameReplace = "googlioa"

' Pad the names...
strNameFind    = Left(strNameFind    & Space(10), 10)
strNameReplace = Left(strNameReplace & Space(10), 10)

MyString = Replace(MyString, strNameFind, strNameReplace)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to determine the existing name, just pad your new name appropriately and add the remainder of your string:

```
' Pad the new name to fit in a 10-char column...
strNameReplace = "googlioa"
strNameReplace = Left(strNameReplace & Space(10), 10)

' Update the record...
MyString = strNameReplace & Mid(MyString, 11)
```